# How to create Multiple images with hyperlinks

Tags: css, photoshop

I have a psd image with me. This image has been created combining multiple images. I want that each of this multiple images must have a seperate alt tag and a hyperlink. When the user clicks on it, he/she should be taken to the that url.

How can I do it. Please suggest me all options like open source or online tools etc.

Comment: Could you please let ut know how the images are layed out? Are they stacked togehter side by side, or some overlay? Give us some more information, please!

Comment: They are stacked together side by side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: [Medialab's SiteGrinder](http://www.medialab.com/sitegrinder3/). This is a PS plugin which transforms your PSD into a working webpage, I use it for prototyping and to figure out px distances and such, there are services out there too, but have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.kromefx.com/index.php?page=vt&id=76) too.

Hope they help.